# extract number from string in kdb

Tags: kdb, q-lang

I am quite new to kdb+q. I've come across this problem of extracting a number out of string.

Any suggestions?

Example:

```
"AZXER_1234_MARKET" should output 1234 //Assume that there is only one number in the
```

string

Answer (score 6):

Extract the numbers then cast to required type.

```
q){"I"$x inter .Q.n} "AZXER_1234_MARKET"
1234i

q){"I"$x inter .Q.n} "AZXER_123411_MARKET"
123411i
q){"I"$x inter .Q.n} "AZXER_1234_56_MARKET"
123456i
q){"I"$x inter .Q.n} "AR_34_56_MAT"
3456i
```

Comment: Nice answer. But I would suggest an alternate for this which is basically the same thing: 
        {"I"$x inter "0123456789"} "AZXER_1234_MARKET"                       
   .Q.n is nothing but "0123456789" but .Q implementation is subjected to change as mentioned in q.k file(\d .Q /DO NOT USE ROUTINES PAST HERE. SUBJECT TO CHANGE). So it is not generally suggested to use it unless you are using any complex feature of it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple numbers, here is a variation of the above, which allows for multiple numbers in one string

```
q)nums:{"I"$((where n&differ  n:x in .Q.n) cut x) inter\: .Q.n}
q)nums "this is 123 and this is 56"
123 56i
```

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest the following if we assume only one number in the string:

```
q)"AZXER_1234_MARKET"inter .Q.n
"1234"
q)"A_5643_B"inter .Q.n
"5643"
```

Then of course you can cast it to any type you want.